# Do every pin of a micro controller associated with a register?

Tags: embedded, port, microcontroller

I'm a beginner in the embedded system development world.
I would like some clarifications on the following questions.

1. Is every pin of a microcontroller (from here after referred to as mc) associated with a register?
2. Is it an one to one relationship?
3. How are ports (or groups of pins) assigned inside the mc?
4. Is it only possible to set a single pin low or high only?

Comment: You would do better to read and understand the datasheet and/or reference manual for the specific microcontroller you intend to use - there are significant variances in I/O architecture, capability and complexity.  The answers to your questions will not get you very far in terms of useful information.  Some grounding (no pun intended) in at least basic electronics would also help.  Then ask something more focused and useful.

Comment: You've tagged the question "PIC" - if your question is specifically about a PIC then ask that - but that covers a wide variety of devices, so you should be more specific in the question.  If your question is not specifically about PIC devices, then you should not tag it as such.

Comment: @Clifford It will be very useful if you could suggest some websites or books to start with in the field of embedded systems.Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No. Some pins are not associated with a register at all, e.g. Vcc and GND and if they do not have a dual use as a GPIO it also applies to clock/oscillator and reset pins.
2. If a pin is associated with registers, it is usually associated with several ones: one for determing the IO direction, one for reading the input, one or more for setting the output. For I2C, SPI, UART pins, the associated is indirect, i.e. the register mainly control the I2C/SPI/UART controller, which in turn is associated with the pin.
3. *I don't understand the question*
4. A GPIO pin can be set as input, as output in high state (delivering current or with a weak pull-up), as output in low state (sourcing current or with a weak pull-down) or in open-drain state (often similar to input mode). A pin can also be configured to be used by one fo the I2C/SPI/UART controllers or as DAC (outputting a variable voltage between GND and Vcc).

Comment: I think you answered 3. with your explanation of the multiple registers associated with a pin in 2.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to fundamental stuff like supply and clock pins, a MCU got numerous *hardware peripherals* internally. A hardware peripheral being something like a piece of GPIO (general-purpose input/output), ADC, UART, SPI etc. Each such hardware peripheral has a number of possible pins to which its functions can be routed.

Traditionally, these were pretty much fixed - if you wanted UART Tx then you would always get it on some fixed pin number, take it or leave it. Nowadays, most MCUs are quite flexible internally, allowing you to re-route hardware peripheral functionality to almost any pin you like, variably.

In either case, several hardware peripherals could share the same pin, and then it is MCU specific which one that takes precedence. For example GPIO could be present on the pin by default, but if you enable UART then maybe the MCU states that you get UART Tx on that pin instead.

As for the hardware peripheral called GPIO, they are almost always grouped in *ports*, where each port consists of a number of pins. Most often, port registers are either 8 bits or the size of the CPU's word length. Each bit in the various port registers corresponds to a pin.

You'll have a port data register, which is the actual read/write to the pin, a data direction register stating input or output, and then various other registers for interrupts, pull resistor enable etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not all pins but all IOs (Input/Output) have a specific register.
2. Each IO has a specific group of registers. Bu also some registers may include specific bits which effects an IO or all IOs.
3. It depends of design of micro controller.
4. Yes it is.

I strongly recommend you to read some embedded hardware/software books(for example Newness Know It All books for embedded systems) and datasheets.